# Fermentation of different types of sugar

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, carbohydrates

I'm searching for the difference in the fermentation of muscovado sugar, honey and sugar cane. I have used a specific microbiota to to ferment these three types of sugar and have to explain why I've got different results regarding acetic acid and ethanol production in the final beverage, as well as different amounts of sucrose, glucose and fructose in same.

Answer (score 1):

Micro-organisms eat the sugars then excrete all sorts of compounds. Acetic acid and/or ethanol is commonly excreted by anaerobic organisms.  Anaerobic organisms can derive energy from multiple reaction paths, even within the same micro-organism (consider the case of facultative anaerobes.)

Since the same organism can use different paths to derive it is quite natural to assume what comes out is naturally affected by what goes in.